# Joomla user registration plugin

Tags: joomla

I am interested in customizing the authentication method for a Joomla website.

There is a comprehensive tutorial on [how to make a custom authentication plug-in](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla_1.5), however a plug-in of that sort customizes the behavior on **each** log-in.

The behavior I need to implement should occur only **once** during registration. Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a user plugin that responds to the `onBeforeStoreUser` event instead of an authentication plugin. The plugin creation process is much the same for user plugins. The `onBeforeStoreUser` event receives two arguments: the user object and a boolean flag indicating whether or not the user is a new one.

You can look at `plugins/user/example.php` to see all of the user plugin event handlers.

Comment: And for newer versions, the event is `onUserBeforeSave`